# Unterschied zwischen "ausgewogen" und "ausgeglichen"

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen generellen Unterschied zwischen "ausgewogen" und "ausgeglichen", also welche Substantive passen zu dem einen und welche zum​ anderen Wort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grundsätzlich glaube ich, dass sich die Mengen der Einsatzmöglichkeiten der beiden Worte sich stark überschneidet und man sie auch (in der Regel) synonym verwenden kann (der Duden listet sie auch als Synonyme voneinander). Im Großen und Ganze haben sich nur verschiedene Kontexte eingebürgert, in denen nur das eine oder das andere Wort genutzt werden.

Hier ist beispielsweise der Unterschied, dass "ausgeglichen" den aktuell sichtbaren Zustand und "ausgewogen" die grundsätzliche Beschaffenheit von etwas beschreibt:

> Ein Spiel ist ausgeglichen, wenn beide Parteien gleich gut sind. 
>   Ein Spiel ist ausgewogen, wenn die Regeln des Spiels gut sind.
>
> Die Waage ist ausgeglichen, wenn auf beiden Seiten das gleiche Gewicht
>   liegt.
>   Eine Waage ist ausgewogen, wenn ihr Design gut ist oder ihre Preis-Leistung stimmt.

Ohne, dass ich eine Regel daraus schmieden könnte:
Ein Mensch ist ausgeglichen, nicht ausgewogen. Sein Charakter jedoch kann wieder beides sein.

Beiden zugehörigen Verben ist das wesentlich einfacher:
Ausgleichen heißt das Ungleichgewicht mehrerer Entitäten zu beseitigen.
Auswiegen bedeutet das Gewicht von etwas genau feststellen.

Comment: Eine Waage ist ausgewogen, wenn sie geeicht ist, hätte ich gedacht :)
Außerdem: „Peter ist ausgeglichen.“ bedeutet, dass er nicht leicht aus der Ruhe gerät. „Peter ist ausgewogen.“ bedeutet für mich gar nichts.

Comment: Ausgewogen kann Whisky, Kaffee oder Wein sein, wenn wir verschiedene geschmackliche Nuancen interpretieren. Es kann sich auch auf Technik beziehen, z. B. könnte man sagen, „Klitschkos Technik ist ausgewogen.“, d. h. er favorisiert nicht Verteidigung über Angriff (oder umgekehrt).
All das geht mit ausgeglichen nicht.

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt fällt mir auf Anhieb kein Beispiel ein, bei dem man, um das selbe auszudrücken, die beiden Wörter einfach austauschen könnte. Von Synonymen würde ich daher nicht sprechen, und auch nicht davon, „dass sich die Mengen der Einsatzmöglichkeiten der beiden Worte sich stark überschneidet und man sie auch (in der Regel) synonym verwenden kann“. Deshalb -1.

Comment: Bei den geschmacklichen Nuancen würde ich auch beides akzeptieren, auch wenn "ausgeglichen" tendenziell eher auf eine metaphorische Bedeutung abzielt.
Mit der Synonymität habe ich mich auf den Duden berufen, glaube aber auch, dass man im Zweifelsfall den Satz umstellen/ändern muss um den gleichen Sinn zu erreichen. Im Satz  "Er ist ein ausgewogener/ausgeglichener Charakter." finde ich aber beispielsweise beides passend.